# Android Keyboard Not showing up (not working accross any apps)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-7.0-nougat, huawei-mobile-services

**Phone** : `HUAWEI`
**ANDROID** : `7.0`

*When I tap on any textfield in any of my applications on the phone, the keyboard is no longer displaying.*

I tried:
`Restart`,
`Power Off, Wait, Power On`

None of the above worked. The only thing that seemed to work is actually downloading another keyboard (i tried 'swiftkey').

> Yes, downloading a new keyboard worked perfectly fine but **i'd really like to know what happened for the keyboard to just stop showing up like that**. I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Please comment if i missed any required information && thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether keyboard will showing in other app when it can't show in your app?Could you post your manifest.xml code and your activity's layout file code?

Comment: @Aolphn this isn't code related at all. Should i remove my question and if so, where can i post this for an answer ?

Comment: I mean in facebook or other app whether your phone can show keyboard?If not then check your keyboard settings.

Comment: @Aolphn , i checked Facebook, Whatsapp, even just messages ... the keyboard just won't come up.